# how to evenly apply a texture to a mesh (UVs)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, mesh

Good afternoon/evening! We need your help! I am writing a character editor on unity and faced with such a problem: how can I apply the texture evenly on the mesh, so that the texture does not stretch over the entire polygon and does not shrink?
[image]

```
List<Vector2> UVs = new List<Vector2>();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i += 4)
        {
            UVs.Add(new Vector2(1f,1f));
            UVs.Add(new Vector2(0f,1f));
            UVs.Add(new Vector2(0f,0f));
            UVs.Add(new Vector2(1f,0f));
        }
        MeshSide.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.SetUVs(0, UVs);
```